# Before validation method breaking spec with 'undefined method downcase'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, rspec

In my User model I have a before_validation method called normalize_params that uses downcase.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  before_validation :normalize_params, on: [:create, :update]

  validates :email, :presence => true
  validates :email, :uniqueness => true

  validates :username, :presence => true
  validates :username, :uniqueness => true

  validates_confirmation_of :password

  scope :all_users_except, -> (current_user) {
    where.not(id: current_user)
  }

  has_attached_file :avatar, styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: 
  "100x100>" }, default_url: "/images/missing.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, content_type: 
  /\Aimage\/.*\z/
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  private

  def normalize_params
    self.name = name.downcase.titleize
    self.email = email.downcase
    self.home = home.downcase.titleize
  end
end
```

All of that works perfectly in my app but my tests break when they hit the downcase with this error...

```
NoMethodError:
  undefined method `downcase' for nil:NilClass
```

Here are my tests...

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe User, 'validation' do
  it { should validate_presence_of :email }
  it { should validate_presence_of :username }
  it { should validate_presence_of :password }
end
```

If I take before_validation and normalize_params out then my tests pass.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) exemplifies, you could use `attribute_present?` before:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  before_validation :normalize_params, on: %i[create update]

  validates :email,    presence: true, uniqueness: true
  validates :username, presence: true, uniqueness: true

  private

  def normalize_params
    titleize_name
    downcase_email
    # You can any other here.
  end

  def titleize_name
    self.name = name.downcase.titleize if attribute_present? 'name'
  end

  def downcase_email
    self.email = email.downcase if attribute_present? 'email'
  end
end
```

Note you can:

- Use [`%i[]`](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#percent-i) to create an array of symbols.
- Validates presence and uniqueness by separating them by comma.
- Prefer the `is_expected.to` than `should` syntax (`it { is_expected.to validate_presence_of :attribute }`)
- Separate each of your attribute modifications to easily work and include them.
- Avoid using hash rocket when not needed. See [`ruby-style-guide#hash-literals`](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#hash-literals).

Comment: That fixed it. Thanks for the extra info as well.

Comment: TBH, there’s absolutely no difference between `should` and `is_expected.to` for inline expectations (according to RSpec docs) other than style preference. I, personally, think it’s just more verbosity with no added benefits.

Answer (score 2):

Either one of `name`, `email` or `home` may be `nil`. I'd recommend using the [safe navigation operator](http://mitrev.net/ruby/2015/11/13/the-operator-in-ruby/):

```
def normalize_params
  self.name = name&.downcase&.titleize
  self.email = email&.downcase
  self.home = home&.downcase&.titleize
end
```

Comment: Thanks for posting. That also fixed my test. I'd never heard of the safe navigation operator before.

Comment: Oh yeah. It took me a while to find out about it too. It’s not very widespread. (In Ruby, that is. Some languages tend to rub it in your face in the docs haha)